# Xcode: CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION in product name

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, xcode7

In Xcode 7, I would like the name of the product to be something like `myapp.3.23` where `myapp` is the target name, 3 is the version and 23 is the build. I tried by setting the product name of my target to `$TARGET_NAME.$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` (and also `$(TARGET_NAME).$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`) but only `$TARGET` seems to work.
Any clue?

**Edit:**
I am trying to do so from Xcode's *Build settings* panel, setting the desired value in the *Packaging* > *Product name* field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_xxx

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you refer to. I would like to set the product name in the dedicated *Product name* field of Xcode's *Build settings*. I edited the question to include this info.

Comment: @StefanoBider what is the attribute name that this maps to in the plist file?

Comment: it should be CFBundleVersion